# How to add "from" and "to" search bars

Tags: android, searchbar

I need to create a screen (activity) where user can select source and destination locations for my custom indoor map. Basically, it must contain "From" and "To" edit controls, so that user can type something and then select from a drop-down list of suggestions.
I know how to do it (and already have done it) in case of single search widget using the SearchView widget as an "action view" in the Action Bar. (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).
Ideally, I want to achieve something looking like Google Maps app:
[image]

How did they do it?
Is this blue rect in the picture an expanded Action Bar containing two search widgets, or is it a custom control which I will need to re-implement from scratch?

Comment: It's **Toolbar** with search, back icon and overflow, below toolbar a simple **EditText** and **TabLayout** below editText. And off-course it's not implement in default Standard UI and you should implement it by your own.

Comment: Have you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a Drawable

Just use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Your_Permenant_hint_text"`

For instance :

.Create a drawable :

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="Hint">Hint</drawable>
</resources>
```

.Set a drawable :

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/detail_text"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Hint"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/detail_text"/>
```

[image: screenshot]